# Format string to add leading zero in 24 hour time

Tags: string, powershell, datetime

I'm using PowerShell's `-match` operator and the regex `\b(Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun).([012]?[0-9][:]\d{2})` to grab the Day and the Time a reboot is supposed to happen.

Sample data:

```
Patching - Prod - Fri 2:00
Patching - Prod - Fri 22:00
Patching - Prod - Thu 22:00
Patching - Prod - Fri 22:00
Patching - Prod - Sat 18:00
Patching - Prod - Sun 2:00
Patching - Prod - Sun 00:00
Patching - Prod - Sat 2:00

$Rebootinfo = "Patching - Prod - Sat 2:00"

"$Rebootinfo" -match "\b(Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun).([012]?[0-9][:]\d{2})" | Out-Null
```

This works great but I've found when the time is `2:00 AM` I get `2:00` and I'm looking to pad that result with a leading zero for `02:00`  also if the time is Midnight, the result would be `0` instead of the desired `00:00`

I have been trying the suggestions from [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/06/02/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-leading-zeroes-when-displaying-a-value-in-windows-powershell/) without success.

```
"Prod - Sun 2:00" -match "\b(Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun).([012]?[0-9][:]\d{2})" | Out-Null

$a = $Matches[2]
$a.ToString("00:00")
```

Returns the error Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".

My goal for doing this is to pass the data into PowerShell to get the number of days until that reboot time.  As an example, Sunday 2 AM needs 1 day added if run on Saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
"Prod - Sun 2:00" -match "\b(Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun).([012]?[0-9][:]\d{2})" | Out-Null
$a = $Matches[2]
$ts = [TimeSpan]::Parse($a)
$formatted = $ts.ToString("c").Substring(0, 5)
$formatted
```

It outputs `02:00` for `$formatted`.

Comment: I ended up using this along with another code snippet getting me the value I was after, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use digit-formatting on a string, so you would need to convert the hours/minutes to int first. Here's a few examples:

```
#Convert 2:00 to 200 int-number and format it to 00:00-style -> 02:00.
#18:00 -> 1800 -> 18:00
"{0:00:00}" -f ([int]$a.Replace(":",""))
```

Or

```
#Capture hour and minutes in their own groups
"Prod - Sun 2:00" -match "\b(Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun).([012]?[0-9])[:](\d{2})" | Out-Null
#Format 00 only works with digits, so convert to int
"{0:00}:{1:00}" -f [int]$Matches[2], [int]$Matches[3]
```

Or you could parse it to DateTime and convert back to string with correct format (or use DateTime-object if you want).

```
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[0], "ddd H:mm", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
$date.ToString("ddd HH:mm", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: @user4317867 Given your question history I'd suggest using the 3rd approach without turning the `DateTime` value back into a string. That will get you the time of the next maintenance window as an actual timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't seem to have a question (a goal, but not a question). So I'll guess that your question is "why doesn't the regex return '02:00AM'"?

Since the source string doesn't contain a zero before the 2 you can't get a match that includes a zero not in source string. You would need to add that as a separate step.

You can avoid some trouble by using .NET's built date time parsing: `[datetime]::parseexact`. Unfortunately ParseExact can't handle a string like "Sun 2:00AM", if Sun is not the current day, so some extra work is required. Here is some same sample code.

```
$Rebootinfo = "Patching - Prod - Thu 2:00AM"

$splitUp = $Rebootinfo -split "\b(Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)"
# $splitUp[-1] now contains time and $splitUp[-2] contains day of week

$cult = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
try {
   $rebootTime = [datetime]::parseexact( $splitUp[-1], " h:mmtt", $cult)
} catch {
   # put your own error handling here
   throw "Date time parse failed"
}

$weekDayToWeekDayNumber = @{Sun=0;Mon=1;Tue=2;Wed=3;Thu=4;Fri=5;Sat=6}
$rebootWeekDayNumber = $weekDayToWeekDayNumber[$splitUp[-2]]
$todayWeekDayNumber = $weekDayToWeekDayNumber[[datetime]::today.DayOfWeek.tostring().substring(0,3)]
# This calculation fails if the reboot day of the week is same as current
# day of week and reboot time is before current time. However I'm guessing 
# this won't be a problem because if this
# happens you've already missed the boot or the boot is almost a week away.
# Assuming the later: since you only have days of the week (and not dates) 
# I'm guessing that
# boots almost a week away aren't a concern. The reason is that if you 
# handle boots almost a
# week away, there's no guarantee (that I see) that the boot won't be a 
# little more than a week away (since you don't know exactly when the boot 
# is, hence the script). And if boots can be more than a week away you won't 
# be able to distinguish between boots this week and boots next week (since
# you only have the day of the week).
# However if this is a problem, just compare $rebootTime to [datetime]::now
# and if less, then add 7 more days to $rebootTime.
$rebootTime = $rebootTime.AddDays( ($rebootWeekDayNumber - $todayWeekDayNumber + 7) % 7)

write-host Amount of time till reboot ($rebootTime - [datetime]::now)
```